# EFCore Postgres timestamp loses tick precision

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm having a problem with my application that is reading from a JSON API that is providing me times in UTC in the following format:

`2019-09-19T23:46:00.1183275Z`

I am storing these times in a Postgres database using Entity Framework Core and using them later to make sure I am only getting newer data from the API. The problem I am having is that when these timestamps are written to the database, I am losing the precision that .NET has down to the ticks of the timestamp. C# has the ticks for the above timestamp as: `637045335601183275`, but when I read that same time back out of the database, the ticks are `637045335601183270`.

I tried searching the documentation but I could not find a way to change the precision of the timestamp in the database. Is there a way? Failing that is there a consistent way to round the `DateTime` to a precision that won't be lost by the database?

Example:

**Context**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(@"host=localhost;port=5432;database=TestDb;user id=postgres;password=password");
    }
}
```

**Item**

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Program**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>("{Id: 1, CreateTime: \"2019-09-19T23:46:00.1183275Z\"}");
        Item readItem;

        using(var context = new MyContext())
        {
            context.Items.Add(item);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using(var context = new MyContext())
        {
            readItem = context.Items.First();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(item.CreateTime.Ticks.Equals(readItem.CreateTime.Ticks)); //Outputs False
    }
}
```

Above created using EFCore 2.2.6 and Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.2.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried searching the documentation but I could not find a way to
>   change the precision of the timestamp in the database. Is there a way?

No, there is not.

Postgres date / time types are alas only accurate [to the microsecond](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) (1 / 1,000,000 second).

.NET dates are measured in [100 nanosecond](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) units called ticks (a tick is 1 / 10,000,000 second).

Since there are 10 ticks to every microsecond, .NET dates are not going to be round trippable through Postgres.

> Failing that is there a consistent way to round the DateTime to a
>   precision that won't be lost by the database?

Yes - `DateTime` has a constructor which takes [`Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_System_DateTimeKind_). You could, therefore, use `item.CreateTime.Ticks` to get your initial ticks value, alter it in some way (decide whether you want to ceiling or floor or round or whatever) and then pass it to the constructor. This value (accurate to the microsecond) would then round trip through Postgres just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do a little more digging with my code. But if the precision is only off by a tens place I should be able to easily round the last digit of the ticks then.

Comment: Yep, round or ceiling or whatever - it should be very simple.

Comment: Snippet to compensate for the last digit discrepancy: var dbPrecisionCreateTime = new DateTime(memoryPrecisionCreateTime.Ticks / 10 * 10)